# What syntax does OllyDbg follow in its dissassembly window?

Tags: disassembly, assembly, ollydbg

I have some understanding of Assembly after reading some tutorials and a few chapters from the "PC Assembly Book". Right now, I am trying to understand the instructions I see in OllyDbg, but it seems to follow a different syntax than the NASM syntax I am used to.

This OllyDbg instruction for example doesn't seem intuitive to me, especially the `PTR SS:` part.

```
MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+8],EBX
```

I am not looking for an explanation of this particular construct, but rather a documentation for the whole syntax. How can I find that?

Comment: "The `PTR SS:` part" is not a separate part at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OllyDbg uses the MASM/Intel syntax for disassembly. You can get the basic documentation at http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html. The [Intel developer manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) can give you more detail about what specific instructions do and what segments mean (in your case the memory location `[ESP+8]` uses the SS segment).

On Windows **user mode** it is safe to ignore all segments (`SS:[ESP+8]` means exactly the same as `DS:[ESP+8]`), only the FS (32 bit) and GS (64 bit) segments have a meaning. See [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block) for more information.

A good resource is [Basics of Assembler](https://www.scribd.com/document/331803715/Basics-of-Assembler) by [Lena151](https://tuts4you.com/download.php?list.17) it should get you up to speed if you're not familiar with (dis)assembly. In [x64dbg](http://x64dbg.com) you can get brief descriptions and the relevant intel manual section for every instruction with a click of the mouse which might come in handy too.